# Ruby: Why i cant define singlteon method on fixnum class

Tags: ruby

I want to define singleton method to every integer value (object) . but i am getting error while applying singleton method.

RubyDoc says `There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value` . what does this mean ?? how it is different from other normal classes??  i am not able to interpret this line.

Comment: Code code Code, people want to see the code

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

> I want to define singleton method to every integer value (object)

This is contradictory. The singleton class is for when you want something to apply to a **single** object. You want to define something for *every* integer object, so the singleton class is not an appropriate tool. Just use the normal class

```
class Integer
  def foobar
    "hey"
  end
end

3.foobar
# "hey"
```

If you could modify the singleton class of 3, then there would be some behaviors that only apply to the number 3 and no other number. There is no technical reason to prevent that, but trust me that it's a good thing that you can't.

> There is effectively only one Fixnum object instance for any given integer value

This is talking about something else. Notice the difference:

```
x = []
y = []
x == y                     # true
x.object_id == y.object_id # false!

x = 3
y = 3
x == y                     # true
x.object_id == y.object_id # true!
x.object_id == 5.object_id # false
```

Unlike most other objects, equal fixnums are identical objects. 3 and 5 are two different instances of Fixnum, but it is impossible to have two different instances of Fixnum that are both 3. Every 3 is the same. Again, this is not a technical necessity but more of a convenience for how most programmers think about numerical data.

Comment: There **is** a technical reason to prevent that, `Fixnum`s (in MRI) are represented as plain C integers, and not structs like every other object, so they **can't** have a singleton class. This of course is just an implementation detail, which made small ints work way faster, but ultimately was decided to remain that way for all ints (`Fixnum`s and `Bignum`s which are now unified under the `Integer` class).

Comment: True, but my point is that it doesn't _need_ to be that way. The language could have been defined/implemented differently without any internal inconsistency. I think this decision was made to be more in line with other OO languages and for efficiency as you point out.

Answer (score 2):

It means that whenever you access some Fixnum, such as the number 1, you’re always treating with the same “instance”, this is mostly an implementation detail which ruby uses to optimize numbers.

Answer (score 2):

The `Integer` class is frozen by default:

```
1.frozen?
 => true
```

There only ever exists one instance of any Integer object. You don't have to do anything special to enable this. In other words, the optimization you are trying to apply is built into Ruby.